# search Whole word only in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to implement **search whole word only** in VBScript, I tried appeding characters like space, /, ],) etc. as these characters means end of word. I need to do as many search as the number of characters I want to include using or operator. Is there any way to do it easily in VBScript.

Currently I am doing :-

```
w_seachString = 
searchString & " " or 
searchString & "/" or 
searchString & "]" or 
searchString & ")" or 
searchString & "}" or 
searchString & "," or 
searchString & "."
```

So eventually I am comparing with lots of combination and looking for an effective way to make my variable  `w_seachString` able to search for whole word only.

Comment: You should use Regexp ==> Take a look at this [search and replace WHOLE WORDS ONLY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728717/search-and-replace-whole-words-only/11729848#comment15565679_11729848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with a word boundary [anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s48y7b93%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Pattern = "\bx\b"
Dim s
For Each s In Split("axb| x |ax|x|\x/|", "|")
    WScript.Echo qq(s), CStr(r.Test(s))
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 36443611.vbs
"axb" False
" x " True
"ax" False
"x" True
"\x/" True
"" False
```

Comment: Great example Ekkehard!