# Access/MS 365 for Enterprise: Find specific text within a string in an Access table's column and update each instance

Tags: sql, vba, module, ms-access-2016, find-replace

I have a file with 80K+ records that I compare to another file in Access to find address changes. The problem is that the data in the address columns are not apples to apples, so using queries I change all instances to match. I then compare to capture true address changes only and not generate a list of 5,000 records that only mismatch based on "apt" versus "apartment", for example. Temporarily, I created way too many queries to do this, but I know it can be done much more simply with a module or two, or a sql query where I can list all the updates I want to do in one query rather than one for each text string. If someone can point me to an answered question  (since nothing seems to relate specifically) or pinpoint the exact function I need, I can do further research and learn how to incorporate it.

Table Name: VendorDemo

Field Name: Home Address 1

FIND "Dr" within the address string of "123 Main Dr" in field Home Address 1 and REPLACE with "123 Main Drive" for all records in the table

Starting Udemy course on it right now, but would like to know what to pay particular attention to and to get a jump start on it.

Comment: Consider a user-defined function employing a regular expression approach to do your replacements: [RegExpReplaceWord example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11729848/77335)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find and replace option in ms access, CTR+F. look closely at the options I picked in the find and replace dialog box.

I have attached the image of the table data before and after the find and replace is done.

[image: Find]

[image: Replace]

[image: table data before replace is done]

[image: table data after replace all is done]

Comment: Hi Sola, This would require more work than the queries/macros I already have built as a temporary solutions. Thanks though!

Comment: Thanks, HansUp! I will pursue your suggestions. I really appreciate the starting point!