# How to make a cell equal to the value of an expression in another cell (Excel 2010)?

Tags: excel

I'm working on a spreadsheet, and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Price Returned      Net Profit

22                  22
45                  45
7                   7
25+25               50
```

The data is being put in as expressions, to denote the return values of specific items. What I can't figure out is how to make the next cell equal to the expression value of the first cell, so essentially as if the cell was "=22" and "=25+25". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple things like that, you can make a UDF:

```
Function Evalu8(ByVal S As String) As String
    Evalu8 = Evaluate(S)
End Function
```

Called, like `=Evalu8(A4)`

Unfortunately, there's no built in worksheet function that'll do it for you, but the VBA [Evaluate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) saves the day.

Comment: Yeah but it's so straightforward :). +1

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll pretend to know what that means and just add it :) You'll be glad to know that your solution worked!

Answer (score 2):

Your question triggered my memory of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula) and @iDevlop's answer, which led to [this post](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/evaluate-function.html) (which in turn has a dead link to Stephen Bullen's web page).

Basically, you can use the Evaluate function, which is actually an undocumented Microsoft XLM macro. You have to use it in a defined name, or you'll get a "The Function is Not Valid" error message. And since it's really a macro, the workbook it's in needs to be saved as a .xlm and macros have to be enabled for it to work. If all that works for you, here's how you'd do it (if it doesn't, have a look at the accepted answer to the SO question above, or @Daniel Cook's answer below which popped up while I was working on this answer):

1. Select B1 in the worksheet with the calculation (Sheet1 in this
   example)
2. Click Ctrl-F3 to open Excel's Name Manager
3. Create a new name and call it `EvaluateCellToLeft`
4. Set the scope to Sheet1
5. In the refers to box, enter `=evaluate(Sheet1!A1)`

This is how it looks in Excel 2010:

[image]

Now in column B enter `=EvaluateCellToLeft`. Remember, it's a named range, not a formula, so there's no parentheses at the end.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I can't think of any reason to do all this rather than just add a macro like @Daniel Cook's. You've got the same macro-enabling requirements with this and less flexibility, i.e., with a name you have to specify the cell to be evaluated. And with his you could put it in an addin, avoiding the macro-enabling requirement, which I'm not sure you can with this. And who knows maybe someday Excel 4 macros will be discontinued.