# In Excel, can I get Data From an External Source (Oracle) that uses the =HYPERLINK("http://url.com", "Pretty Name") function?

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, url, hyperlink

I'm trying to get my URLs in my Pivot Table / Pivot Chart to display as hyperlinks.

I've set up a connection, "From Other Sources," in my case Oracle.  In the SQL statement, I say,

```
SELECT '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com?' || otherStuff || '", "Pretty Name")';
```

This would return to my workbook:
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com?1234567890", "Pretty Name")

However, this stays as text in Excel (   the string "=HYPERLINK...Name")"   ).  I want it to switch to "Pretty Name."

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the version of Microsoft Excel you're using? Also, are you trying to put this formula using VBA or other thing? If possible, please explain with more details.

Comment: Excel 2010.  No VBA currently being used.

Comment: I can get it to convert to the "Friendly Name" -- but only if I edit the field (F2), then hit Enter (because it thinks I'm hand-jamming the =Hyperlink() function in as a user).  There is no "Format cell...as URL" type; it's merely general (or text).

Comment: You might take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula