# Can I Pass one cell value as formula into another cell by equal?

Tags: excel, vba

Here I am going to ask one funny question that is in excel sheet,
Let's consider Cell **B3** contain value as **3*35**, and cell **C3** value is **=B3** as show below

[image]

But my funny expectation is when set **C3** value is **=B3** it must show **C3** value as **105** (I mean I want to make it relevant to **C3=3*35** => **105** ) is it possible.

I hope viewer will understand my question.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, but check out this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula][1]

Answer (score 1):

first of all, typing =3*35 in a cell by itself would have given you the answer right away.

either your question is missing something, like the reason why you want to do it the way you described or you have overlooked something, like using a proper formula.

anyway from your description it sounds like what you want to do is to take a text representation of a formula and then tell excel to calculate it.
if thats what you want then take a look at this question:
[How to turn a string formula into a "real" formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)