# How to calculate/sum numbers in a single cell in excel?

Tags: excel, sum

Example:

In a single cell I want to calculate 10+20+30 and the answer should appear into the next adjacent cell.

Hope this helps in understanding the question.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
I want the answer to be displayed in the adjacent cell and not in the same cell.

Answer (score 1):

The following thread will answer your question.

[How to turn a string formula into a "real" formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

Check article pointed to in the answer by @iDevlop (not the accepted answer). EVALUATE function in a 'name' is probably the easiest way to go.

Edit:

Rough directions:

- Create a new *name* (Eg. *myResult*) and associate its value to evaluating the cell your expression is to by typed in (Eg: assuming your text expression is in cell *A1* of stylesheet *Sheet1*:  `=Evaluate(Sheet1!$A$1)`)
- In the next cell (where you wish the result to be displayed), add a formula that simply evaluates the name you created (Eg: `=myResult`).

How you create a new name depends en the Excel version. On Excel 2010/2013: Formulas -> Name Manager -> Define Name. For older versions, refer to thread mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
Can you be more precise or providing the steps in a sequence from start to end would be helpful also let me know where and how to write the code.

Comment: Edited answer to provide more directions.