# Set SumIFs formula in Excel(97-2003) version using Poi 3.10

Tags: java, excel, apache, excel-formula, apache-poi

I used Poi 3.10 final for setting SUMIFS() formula in Excel(.xls)and I get the below exception:

```
newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
```

'org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Name 'SUMIFS' is completely unknown in the current workbook'

Is there any way to bypass this and set the formula.
Does Poi 3.10 support sumifs() or I have to use a different jar?

Comment: If you have just one criteria for summing, you can also use `SUMIF` instead of `SUMIFS`

Comment: I manually entered =sumifs formula on this (97-3003)worksheet using excel2013. It works fine.
    But this throws error
  {=SUM((ups!A:A="United")*(ups!B:B="UL*")*(ups!C:C))}

Comment: @pnuts Even if array formula to sum works, Here http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html it's given that the {=} type of formulas isn't supported

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((ups!A:A="United")*(ups!B:B="UL*"),ups!C:C) returns 0 instead of 20

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution for this issue and I haven't found a direct one, but there are some workarounds:

1- Using an alternative formula that is supported by Apache POI 3.1. In case of [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) the alternative is [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e), it worked for me.

2- Setting the cell value as an [HSSFRichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html) with the formula as its String (the "=" sign at the beginning of the formula should be included), and converting the field to a formula field using VB or any other method, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula) question might be of help in this case.

3- Same as the 2nd method but without converting the field type to formula. The user of the Workbook has to manually select the cell and press enter for the formula to be evaluated.