# How to link files in excel with a text in the path changing dynamically?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file which needs to fetch data accordingly every week.
Let us say the formula to get data in a cell is

```
=\T:\Datafile\weekdata\2015\Week01\[Summary.xlsx]Sales'!D4
```

I have a cell in the sheet C3 which changes every week accordingly.It will change to week02 next week and i wish the path to change too..to

```
=\T:\Datafile\weekdata\2015\Week02\[Summary.xlsx]Sales'!D4"
```

I tried doing a concatenation to make the path dynamic

```
="\T:\Datafile\weekdata\2015\"&C3&"\[Summary.xlsx]Sales'!D4"
```

but it doesn't seem to work out.I checked evaluate formula and it resolves C3 to Week02 but the value doesn't come in the cell.In stead just the below text

```
\T:\Datafile\weekdata\2015\Week02\[Summary.xlsx]Sales'!D4
```

appears in the cell instead of any number.

Let me know where am i going wrong and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=INDIRECT()`:

```
=INDIRECT("\T:\Datafile\weekdata\2015\"&C3&"[Summary.xlsx]Sales'!D4")
```

This function does exactly what you are trying to do, takes a built string and makes it a cell reference.

Comment: Tried that too..Doesn't work..gives #Ref error.I think Indirect doesn't work on closed files.

Comment: What is the exact text contained in cell `C3`? This indirect should work, but may not if your other worksheet is not open.

Comment: Yeah,my other file will be closed.The exact text in C3 is Week02;which shall change(i am taking care of that by a different formula) every week.Next week it will be Week03.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `=INDIRECT()` is that it only works if the source workbook is open:

> If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value.

(That quote is from https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd)

By googling "excel convert text to formula" I found this SO Q&A: [How to turn a string formula into a "real" formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

If you don't like the VBA solution, I had success with 
iDevlop's `=EVALUATE()` solution.