# VBA calculate string as formula in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I'm reading the formula of a cell in excel, the return value is `E12*(1-F40` and now I need the result of this fomula how it would be, if I entered it into a cell in my worksheet.

I'm trying to improve a plugin which originally wasn't made by me but I know that it worked, when it simply called `Range(returnString)` with `returnString` being `E12*(1-F40` or somehow like this, but I cant get it to work. When I call

```
Range("E12*(1-F40")
```

I get an error saying

> Die Methode "Range" für das Objekt "_Global" ist fehlgeschlagen

a proper translation would be

> Method "Range" failed for object "_Global"

or something similar to that.

My first idea was to add `=` in front and `)` at the end of the string to make it a valid formula but that doesnt work neither.

So how can I say excel to calculate a formula like `=E12*(1-F40)`?

Comment: You might find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Comment: I think that worked, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got your Excel and your VBA a little tangled up there.

You'd need something like `Result = Range("E12").value * (1 - Range("F40").value)`

Or you could fill a cell in with the value which would be something like:

```
Range("A1").value = Range("E12").value * (1 - Range("F40").value)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Nope, I cant calculate it like that because I dont know how the formula looks like :P But my problem is solved in the comment on my question