# Excel summing a text value of an adjacent cell

Tags: excel

Been bashing my head over this for hours.

Here is the data and desired result:

A1 has the string `204+204+204+204+204+204+59`

I need B1 to show the `SUM` of A1

I've managed thus far by just copying and pasting the text into B1 and placing a `=` in front of it i.e. (`=204+204+...` etc.) But I know there has got to be an easier way.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it.

## 1

Open the Name Manager. Control-F3 from the worksheet, and then click the New button.

## 2

For the Name field in the dialog, enter `EVALA`. I just picked this name; it stands for "Evaluate A". But you can pick whatever name you like.

## 3

For the `Refers to` field, enter this

```
=EVALUATE($A1)
```

## 4

Click OK and then Close.

## 5

In B1 enter this formula:

```
=EVALA
```

That's it.

You can now use this formula on any row in the worksheet and it will evaluate whatever is in the column A cell of the row where you enter the formula.

Comment: Woah! Pretty clever.  How come you can use `Evaluate` when creating a named range, but you can't use it as a regular formula? (meaning I can't just type `=Evaluate($a1)` into B1 and get the result)

Comment: @BruceWayne Evaluate() hails from the macro language that Excel used prior to VBA. That was called Excel 4 Macro language. It still lingers in Excel to this day for backward compatibility. For example, besides worksheets and chart sheets, you can create macro sheets; these are for Excel 4 Macros. You cannot use Excel 4 Macros in cell formulas directly, but you can use some of the functions from Excel 4 Macros in the Name Manger.

Comment: Is there some reason they are phasing out `Evaluate()` and the others? I don't think it was replaced by anything, so I'm curious if you know what the thinking might be.  Is there some other function/method of doing things that's preferable over `Evaluate`, or did they just cut it because you gotta start cutting somewhere?

Comment: It has not been cut. VBA is a much more powerful programming language than Excel 4 Macros ever was. But yet they kept the old macro language in there anyways. As far as using it directly from a cell, well you cannot do that with VBA either... but the analog to what I've done here with the Name Manager and the old macro language is using a UDF from VBA; that's how you can use VBA in a cell. Nothing has been cut.

Comment: Now it would be nice if they chose to create a worksheet function EVALUATE() that would basically do the same thing. Not sure why they have never done so!