# excel reference to another work book multiple sheets

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use a formula that would let me copy and paste it down so I dont have to link every-time

The source workbook has tabs named 1,2,3,4,5.....100

I want to use simple formula `='[test.xlsx]1'!$O$117`

but I want to replace `='[test.xlsx]**A1**'!$O$117`

so it is dynamic and I can copy it down

```
='[test.xlsx]B1'!$O$117; where B1 = 2
='[test.xlsx]C1'!$O$117; where C1 = 3
```

I tried `='[SCD PCAP 2Q15 - waterfall.xlsx]&1&'!$O$117`

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by Two step process.

**Step 1** (Thanks to @**Excel Hero** for this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461496/1652222))

**1**
Open the Name Manager. Control-F3 from the worksheet, and then click the New button.

**2**
For the Name field in the dialog, enter EVALXFD. I just picked this name it is using column XFD in it. But you can pick whatever name you like.

**3**
For the Refers to field, enter this

```
=EVALUATE($XFD1)
```

**4**
Click OK and then Close.

**Step 2**

Paste below mentioned formula in last ***`helper`*** column **XFD** (*I am assuming you are not using this column*)

```
=CONCATENATE("='[Test.xlsx]",$A1,"'!$A$1")
```

In B1 enter this formula and drag it down:

```
=EVALXFD
```

That's it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INDIRECT()` function. *E.g.*, with `$A$1 = 2`, `$A$2 = 3`, ..., you can use

```
=INDIRECT("'[test.xlsx]"&B1&"'!$O$117")
```

which Excel will concatenate `=INDIRECT('[test.xlsx]2'!$O$117)` and then evaluate.

Note also that I've written the references above based on copying the formula *down* column B (with references in column A), so the row number will change, but the reference will always be to column A.