# How to make formula in text format to execute in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

If I have cell A1 containing `'6*2+8*5+7*4` and I want this calculation to execute in cell A2, so every time I change something in Cell A1 the value of cell A2 will change accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn a string formula into a "real" formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) can take a string that looks like a foirmula and return a resolved result.

```
function eval_text(rng as range)
   eval_text = application.evaluate(rng.text)
end function
```

In B1 as `=eval_text(A1)` returns 80.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without VBA:

## 1

Open the Name Manager. Control-F3 from the worksheet, and then click the New button.

## 2

For the Name field in the dialog, enter `EVALA`. I just picked this name; it stands for "Evaluate A". But you can pick whatever name you like.

## 3

For the `Refers to` field, enter this

```
=EVALUATE($A1)
```

## 4

Click OK and then Close.

## 5

In B1 enter this formula:

```
=EVALA
```

That's it.

You can now use this formula on any row in the worksheet and it will evaluate whatever is in the column A cell of the row where you enter the formula.

Comment: I don't think you can include the equals symbol inside the cell in this particular instance. The formula parser would not like the single apostrophe.

Comment: True... but I often see that term used to describe a value entered with a prepended apostrohe in a cell that has the General number format applied. Perhaps OP can let us know what he meant.