# An excel formula that returns from text an excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

In my spreadsheet I have certain formulas that give as output *texts* of the form: `A1+B3+D9`.

These are cell references, the cell rows and columns are calculated automatically within the original formula.

I would like this to be a formula that then gets evaluated. At present I simply copy-special paste as *value* and then by hand put an `=` at the front.

Is there an excel command that does this automatically? i.e. takes a text input, interprets the input as an excel formula and hence evaluates it accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Comment: Probably the best answer lies in the formula that creates this “output texts”, would mind posting a sample of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tweak the formula to get something like

```
=Indirect(A1) + Indirect(B3) + Indirect(D9)
```

otherwise, there is no way to get it without VBA.