# How can I add a cell's text into an excel formula?

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a logical operator variable (>,<,=) based on the user's input.

My main goal is to add a string of text as the logical expression of an if statement. For example I want to take =(A22&A23&A24) which will yield 3>2 in cell A26.

Then I want to take the text of A26 and place it into an if statement:

=IF(A26, True, False) which if I were to just type in 3>2 would give me True. However I just get #VALUE. I've tried converting it to text, copy and pasting it with just the values but I always get #VALUE.

Any ideas?

Comment: Excel will not evaluate text strings as formulas. You will need to write a User Defined Function to do that. And I cannot reproduce typing `3>2` into `A26`, and having that formula of yours return `TRUE`.  Rather it returns `#VALUE!`

Comment: I just meant if I type in =IF(3>2, True, False) it will return True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need VBA, `Indirect()` won't work, AFAIK.

Enter this into a workbook module:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Then, you can do `=If(eval(A26),True,False)`.

(Thanks to [@Fionnuala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4472067/4650297))

Comment: This should be a comment if you're gonna copy verbatim XD

Comment: Holy Hallelujah Batman! It worked! Just for anyone else's reference you need to name the Eval or else you will get an ambiguous error

Comment: @findwindow - Ah, sorry, should I just make these comments if it's basically someone else's answer? Or should we flag the question as duplicate?

Comment: Well, we rarely flag duplicates even though the majority of questions on SO has been answered in some variation XD