# convert text based number to actual number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I convert numbers in the format such as `0.8805*0.1` to actual number?

In my case above, the result should be `0.08805`. I would like to apply this to a huge number of columns and rows.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have cells with the strings like `0.8805*0.1` and want them calculated? If so, could you give a small sample? And: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding = infront of my cell, but it causes an error. Possibly due to excel not recognizing decimal numbers formatted with . sign. I am on mac.

Comment: If it's as @Tom suggest then this will work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula.  Take note of the comment left by Tim Williams though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows. so i purposely put decimal point as ",".

[image]

First thing to do is replace the commas into points (or points to commas to suit your need in mac). so in B1, i convert it with `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")`.

For formula in C1, first select the cell you want to place the calculated output (its C1 in my example), then create a name range as follow with the formula `=EVALUATE(Sheet1!B1)`. After that place the formula `=EvaluateIt` in C1.

[image]

after that just fill down the formula and you can convert text formula into its calculated value.

[image]