# Excel re-use range that is used by another function

Tags: excel, function, range

I have a cell C1, where C1 =AVERAGE(E1:E10).
In cell D1 I would like to have D1 =STDEVP(E1:E10) without explicitly typing the range E1:E10 as I need to use this and other ranges multiple times.

Is there a simple way to get/refer to the affected range in C1 for use by another function in another cell? Something like D1 =STDEVP(AFFECTEDRANGE(C1)).

I found a function called INDIRECT which roughly does what I want, but it requires additional columns for my purpose. As I prefer to keep my worksheet clean and compact I'd prefer a function as described above. Does a one-liner like this exist?

Comment: The best method is INDIRECT.  You can also try parsing the FORMULATEXT() to get the range but you will still need to wrap that in INDIRECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: I merged the answer of Jeeped with the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula) post to create a custom reusable function that does what I need.

It now works by setting `=AverageToStDev(CELL)` as a value for any cell. Note that CELL must be a single cell containing the AVERAGE() function for this to work.

```
Function AverageToStDev(MyCell As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    AverageToStDev = Evaluate(Replace(MyCell.Formula, "AVERAGE", "STDEVP", vbTextCompare))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241892.aspx) on the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) would seem to be sufficient.

```
range("d1").formula = replace(range("c1").formula, "AVERAGE", "STDEVP", vbtextcompare)
```

If you want to stay within the worksheet and avoid VBA, use named ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I adapted your code to fit my exact needs