# Excel addition of multiple numbers in single cell

Tags: excel, ms-office

So i have an Excel document where I have cells with data `4+6` `5+3` `3+5` etc. how can I add them up in such a format? So for example if i have `5+2` if will be `7` in a different cell. It is a preexisting document so I can't simply split the data  into more cells and add them up with a basic SUM()

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **E3**, in **E4** enter:

```
=--MID(E3,1,FIND("+",E3,1)-1)+MID(E3,FIND("+",E3),9999)
```

[image]

this should be for for any data like *1234+8765*

Comment: I see what you did but i don't understand the -- part. Also in my excel the formatting was a bit different (i have to use a semicolon not a comma) =MID(E3;1;FIND("+";E3;1)-1)+MID(E3;FIND("+";E3);9999)

Comment: @SmornikWafflehouse  The ***++*** insures text is converted to number.