# Excel - Indirect Formula not working with 3d reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I need to get sum of cell A1 of sheets from 1 to 5. It works fine with the direct formula which shows below:

```
=SUM('1:5'!A$1)
```

I also need to delete these sheets anytime and recreate them. As soon as I delete sheets `1:5`, the formula results in `#REF` error.

To avoid this issue, I used indirect formula like below:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'1:5'!A1"))
```

However, it did not work and gave me `#REF` error. What I am doing wrong in above formula?

Below is a link to sample file if you need it:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7gzonuQsNbvS3R5MXRUX294cFU

Comment: Something like this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula.

Comment: `INDIRECT` won't accept a 3D sheet reference. Default solution is using sheets named "start" and "end" which are empty and does not be changed or deleted at all. Then a `=SUM(start:end!A1)` will sum all values `A1` of all sheets placed between the sheets named "start" and "end".

Comment: Possibly useful: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/921098-3d-sum-using-indirect-function.html

Comment: @KirillBulygin: This seems to be a good solution. Will it be good performance-wise too?

Comment: @Tejas Well, I think this depends on how a specific version of Excel handles such re-evaluations, there were different approaches on the referenced page. Another thing to try is to put your recreateble sheets into a separate file and see if the references to that file don't break when you recreate the sheets.