# Excel Vlookup to Return Formula works except with Indirect function in it

Tags: excel, function, vlookup, formulas, vba

I need to create do a vlookup that will return a formula then evaluate the formula that it returns.  I have looked it up and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula) that gets me half way there.

I have to add this user defined function to the workbook:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
     Application.Volatile
     Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Then, I can use Eval to return a formula and evaluate it.  It works when I return a normal formula but the minute I put an Indirect function in to the returned formula, it stops working.  I need the Indirect function because the workbook this will finally be used in, I will not know which row it will be on.

The [workbook](http://www.filetolink.com/3b6a34819c) that I have included shows a basic formula (works), formula replaced with an Indirect function (works), Vlookup to find formula (works), Eval with Vlookup to show formula result (works), Eval with Indirect formula (doesn't work), Eval with vlookup to show formula with indirect result (Doesn't work)

so the eval function stops working when ever the indirect function is added.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide example data & formula that don't require downloading binary files from unknown internet sources? kthx.

Comment: @DavidZemens, any formula.  That Data is irrelevant but try this INDIRECT("H"&ROW())*30 and =eval(VLOOKUP(G2,A:C,2,FALSE))

Comment: is that one formula or two? and how do they relate if two.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I explain in my question above.  The first formula will sit in a cell and the second formula will return the first formula and evaluate it.

Comment: @ScottCraner that is why I added the file

Comment: You are not going to get people to open a macro enabled workbook from the web.  It is better to post as text directly to the question.

Comment: =eval(VLOOKUP(G2,A:C,2,FALSE)) returns an error. Unsure what you're actually asking.

Comment: @DavidZemens, it shouldn't return an error though.

Comment: @DavidZemens, do that same exact formula that the eval is working on without the indirect function and it will work. OR do that formula directly with the indirect function and it will work.

Comment: Use this instead of INDIRECT: `INDEX(H:H,row())*30`  The issue is getting the number of  `"` correct,  The Index does not have that.

Comment: @ScottCraner, add that as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX instead of INDIRECT.

```
INDEX(H:H,row())*30
```

The issue is getting the number of `"` correct.

[image]

I would also use `Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate` to ensure that the correct sheet is being used.

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
     Application.Volatile
     Eval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```