# Excel - Referencing a formula operator from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to reference text from various cells to construct a formula in a different cell?

Example:

A1 = 1

A2 = >

A3 = 0

=IF(CONCATENATE(A1:A3),1,0) returns 1

This obviously returns an error, but I'm hoping there's a function that does something like this.

Also I'd like to avoid using if statements since I have quite a few values that can populate the reference cells. (EX:  IF(A2="<",...,IF(A2=">",...)))

Comment: Maybe this might help: [How to turn a string formula into a real formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

Comment: Does the workbook have to be macro free, I'm not sure there is any formulated solution to concatenate an array... I could knock up a UDF for this in a few minutes though

Comment: Just to clarify, `Concatenate(A1:A3)` returns `1` which equates to a binary `TRUE` which is why the IF statement is behaving this way.

Comment: Thuro's link worked. Someone posted an EVALUATE function as VBA in one of the comments which is what I needed.