# How to evaluate the content of another cell in the same spreadsheet without any VBA or any other addon

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

With the cell A1 containing a formula saved as string. Ex: Sum(B1:B5)

In A2 I want to execute content of A1. But when I put =(=A1) in A2 excel gives me formula error. Is there any way I can execute content of A1 in A2 as formula
Mind you no VBA is allowed. Can someone please help?

Please only those people should answer who have done this thing in the past. No hit and tries please

Comment: instead of =(=A1), just type =A1.

Comment: So what do you want your cell A2 to show?

Comment: @Pierre44 Simple as that. I want content of a1 to be evaluated in a2. Is that clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn a string formula into a "real" formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

Answer (score 0):

=A1

that's all you need to point the value to the value in cell A1

Comment: No i do not need the value. I need the value to be evaluated as formula.

Comment: Please do not post random answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Evaluate function doesn't exist in Excel anymore. 
The only way you can use to evaluate properly is unfortunately only VBA.

In addition to the good answer of Durgaprasad. Here are some other ways to evaluate in the related question:

[How to turn a string formula into a "real" formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

Answer (score 0):

**With VBA :**

with VBA you can write some custom function and then evaluate the formula.
Then call the function in excel wherever you required like below

```
=eval_formula(A1)

Function eval_formula(fr)
    eval_formula = Evaluate(fr.Value)
End Function
```

Refer the link here for more details

https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

**without VBA:**

Create a named range and use the named range inside the cell, I have attached the screenshots for your reference

[image: Name Manager]

[image]

hope this is what you required.

Comment: Excel had this function Evaluate() which exactly doing what you need here. But I dont find this in recent versions, where VBA still have this evaluate().

Also using the same evaluate function with name manager gives what you required without VBA.

try this link

http://www.exceltoxl.com/index.php?p=383&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1