# Excel - sum cell values divided by "plus"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell (A1 which have the text "3+2". On the next cell I need to put a formula which is "=A1+1".
How can I tell excel that it has to do the sum on A1, so he can sum another values?
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **A1** contains something like

```
 number+number
```

then in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1)+MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,999)+1
```

[image]

If **A1** contains an arbitrary numeric expression as text, you would use a VBA UDF.

**EDIT#1:**

If you have a list of values separated by the ***+*** sign, then you can use this array formula:

```
=SUM((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",REPT(" ",255)),1+(ROW(A1:A999)-1)*255,255)) & "0")/10)+1
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but in cases where I can have "2+4+3" or "2+7+7+6" I'm screwed

Comment: @FilipePires  You could use a VBA UDF.

Comment: Not a solution in this case.

Comment: @FilipePires  I can give you the UDF() if you want it

Comment: @FilipePires  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Perfect, edit #1 worked as I needed. Can you explain me what's happening on that formula? Just to understand it.

Comment: @FilipePires   The formula creates an internal array of values that it then sums.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use EVALUATE function. It is best way to do it without VBA, however needs simple trick:

While being in cell B1 add to name manager range "Result" with formula

```
=EVALUATE($A1)
```

Than just place in B1 formula

```
=Result
```

For more comprehensive description regarding EVALUATE function please refer to [this](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function) link. Additionaly please notice that EVALUATE function can have different name in your local language.

Btw. similar topic was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula)

Comment: If you do not use the $ (ie `=EVALUATE(A1)`)   then when you enter `=result`, it will always evaluate the contents of the cell to the left.  IF A2 was selected when creating the named formula instead of B1, then it would always evaluate the contents of the cell above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your `x+xxx+xxxxxxxxxxxx` value in cell A1, consider the following formula below:

```
=SUM(0+TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("+"&A1,"+",REPT(" ",99)),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","")))))*99,99)))
```

When you return the formula, be sure to press `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER`. You can then just drag it down for your other additions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a VB Macro:

1. Open the Tools>Macro>Visual Basic Editor
2. Right click to Create a new Module (important!)
3. Double click on the just created new module and paste this code

   ```
   Public Function EvaluateString(strTextString As String)
       Application.Volatile
       EvaluateString = Evaluate(strTextString)
   End Function
   ```
4. Close the VB editor window
5. Now you can use `=EvaluateString(A1)` to get the corresponding value of A1.